# theme switching, template and css file layout on a django site

Tags: django, theming

In my django site I want to offer several themes for our best clients and for the boss. So I quickly created the following. - I am glad i got along to present it but there are a few dirty hacks I want to eliminate with nice solutions I ask you for.

Here's my hack

base.html says (take care - ugly!)

```
{% ifequal theme "0" %}
    {% include "base_d0.html" %}
{% endifequal %}

{% ifequal theme "1" %}
    {% include "base_d1.html" %}
{% endifequal %}

{% ifequal theme "2" %}
    {% include "base_d2.html" %}
{% endifequal %}
```

Then i kept in MEDIA dir the subdirs for all common css and js

and created subdirs

```
static/
  d0/     ( all theme 0 stuff )
    css/
    js/
  d1/     ( all theme 1 stuff )
    css/
    js/
  ...
  css/
    (all common css)
  js/
    (all common js)
```

My controller has a method to switch design, current one is stored in a cookie. It is checked on every request and in template a `PREFIX_STATIC` context variable accordingly to `/mypathto/static/d0 resp. +d1 +d2`  and of course i had to invent a `COMMON_STATIC` var. And the theme var is set too for the base.html switch.

Of course i googled even before starting but found it hard to find good search terms (as i expect there are many good resources )

Comment: i admit i havent checked if the blocks are filled, it does not work that way it seems. My question would be : How just make django choose between several base.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

from loader_tags.py Include_Node  do_extends doc:

```
This tag may be used in two ways: ``{% extends "base" %}`` (with quotes)
uses the literal value "base" as the name of the parent template to extend,
or ``{% extends variable %}`` uses the value of ``variable`` as either the
name of the parent template to extend (if it evaluates to a string) or as
the parent tempate itelf (if it evaluates to a Template object).
```

So i changed my templates to do

```
{% extends base %}
```

instead of

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
```

and set context var "base" as `theme + "/base.html"` in my main controller before i call get_template