# Django: Load template at runtime

Tags: django, django-templates

I am trying to implement a plugin system with the app in my Django project.

I am using Django 2.2 with Python 3.7 in a virtual environment and I have a method that loads the plugin (app). Then I have the applications in the apps directory and at runtime if the user installs one of these plugin (app)

1. I load the app in the INSTALLED_APPS variable (works fine).
2. I create and execute the migrations (works fine).
3. Charge the app url in the main urlpatterns (works fine).

   ```
   def InstallApps(self, pk):
       app = PyApp.objects.get(id=pk)
       app.installed = True
       app.save()
       with open("installed_apps.py", "a+") as installed_apps_file:
           if installed_apps_file.write("apps{}\n".format(app.name.lower())):
               print("yes")
           else:
               print("no")

       # I load the app in the settings.INSTALLED_APPS variable
       with open("%s/installed_apps.py" % BASE_DIR, "r") as ins_apps_file:
           for line in ins_apps_file.readlines():
               settings.INSTALLED_APPS += (line.strip().rstrip("\n"), )

       apps.app_configs = OrderedDict()
       apps.apps_ready = apps.models_ready = apps.loading = apps.ready = False
       apps.clear_cache()

       apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)

       # Create and execute the migrations
       call_command("makemigrations", app.name.lower(), interactive=False)
       call_command("migrate", app.name.lower(), interactive=False)

       # Reload urlpatterns in memory
       urlconf = settings.ROOT_URLCONF
       if urlconf in sys.modules:
           clear_url_caches()
           reload(sys.modules[urlconf])

       return redirect(reverse("base:apps"))
   ```

The problem is that when I try to navigate over the url of the recently installed plugin (app) it tells me that it doesn't find any of the templates of that plugin (app):

> Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
>
> Using engine django:
>
> - django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: $BASE_DIR/templates/sale/menu.html (Source does not exist)
>
> ...
>
> - django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: $BASE_DIR/apps/base/templates/sale/menu.html (Source does not exist)

Django should look for templates for the new pluggin(app) installed in: **$BASE_DIR/apps/sale/templates/sale/menu.html**

If I stop the server and start it again, everything works fine

Is there any way to solve this? Is there a way to reload the TEMPLATES variable from the settings.py file without restarting the server?

settings.py

```
...
    TEMPLATES = [
        {
            'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
            'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
            'APP_DIRS': True,
            'OPTIONS': {
                'context_processors': [
                    'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                    'django.template.context_processors.request',
                    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                    'django_settings_export.settings_export',
                    'django.template.context_processors.i18n',
                    'django.template.context_processors.media',
                    'django.template.context_processors.static',
                    'django.template.context_processors.tz',
                    'django.template.context_processors.csrf',

                ],
            },
        },
    ]
...
```

Thanks

Comment: Can we see your templates info from settings.py?

Comment: What does `TEMPLATES =` equal?

Comment: I edited the answer and put my TEMPLATE from settings. Thanks

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4230299/dynamically-add-to-template-dirs-at-runtime-with-a-django-project can be helpful.